# Extracting images through coordinates from Google Earth in PNG format using Python

Tags: python, google-earth, pysimplegui

I've got this thing to do, when we give coordinates (the latitude and longitude) as an input then the required map should be shown in the output with the help of PySimpleGUI, in Python language, of course.
So, any ideas on how to start this thing?

Comment: Open PyCharm?

import PySimpleGUI as sg

Comment: As far as I know, there is currently no API for Google Earth. You can use Selenium to open Google Earth with the given coordinates in the browser, to take a screenshot and save it as PNG and then open the image using PySimpleGUI.  Or you may want to check the Earth Engine API.

Comment: Hey! Could you please provide me the code, it's just that my deadline for this is coming soon and also I don't even know anything about this topic. Also, I've been trying all types of things from past 7 days and it ain't working out. It would be very kind of you, if you provide me the code. Please, it would be very helpful.

Comment: And yes, there is API for google earth. It would be helpful if you show me the code.

Comment: The Google Earth API was deprecated in 2014 (https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/maps-platform/announcing-deprecation-google-earth-api), and the new version of Google Earth does not have an API at this time.  By the way, welcome to Stackoverflow, and you should know that the recommended practice here is to ask questions that include the code you already tried, and what didn't work.  That way the community can help you debug.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show a map with a satellite image for a given lat/lon coordinate, take a look at Google's "Maps Static API".  All you have to do is generate a URL with the appropriate parameters, and this API will return an image of your place and zoom level (and other parameters).  As the name implies, it generates a static map image, instead of the interactive maps generated through the normal Maps APIs.

More info in the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/overview

Not that if you are thinking about "extracting" images from these maps, make sure to review the terms of service, which generally prohibit bulk extraction of data.  https://www.google.com/help/terms_maps/

Comment: Yeah, thanks for that. But, I need satellite images from Google Earth not from Google maps.

Comment: In Google Maps, and in the Maps API, you can specify the satellite imagery layer (instead of the default map layer), and you'll get the same imagery as in Google Earth.